# Read JSON and plot it with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have this JSON:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "55afa124168fa1652ce4df21",
        "title": "My New Book",
        "genre": "Fiction",
        "author": "Jon Mills",
        "__v": 0,
        "read": false,
        "links": {
            "self": "/api/books/55afa124168fa1652ce4df21"
        }
    }
]
```

How do I display a list of author and title?

This is what I have tried so far:

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in _id">
      {{ x.title + ', ' + x.author }}
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```javascript
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("api/books")

.success(function (response) {
alert("Response:" + response.title + " - " + response.author)
     }
   }
 alert(vals);
}
});
});
```

Comment: `data[0].title` and `data[0].author`

Comment: The JSON is pulled from a API URL - how do I intergrate that?

Comment: A little bit more code would be helpful ;)

Comment: Have you actually tried anything? Check the 500+ tutorials online, if you can't get your code working you can post it here...

Comment: Posted what I have tried so far...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example :

**Controler Js**

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

function TestCtrl($scope,$http) {

  $http.get("api/books").success(function (response) {
     $scope.dataList = response;
  });

}
```

**Html File**

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="data in dataList">
      {{ data.title}} , {{data.author }}
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How would you do this with more than one item in the JSON file?

Answer (score 1):

You can not access **title** and **author** through **_id** because property can not be accessible with another property 
for ex:

```
var obj={
x:1,
y:2
}
```

*where I cannot write x.y it will be an invalid expression*

If you want to iterate you can do this with data

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

 <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="x in data">
    {{ x.title}} ,  {{ x.author }}
   </li>
</ul>
```

Angular

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.data = [{
  "_id": "55afa124168fa1652ce4df21",
  "title": "My New Book",
  "genre": "Fiction",
  "author": "Jon Mills",
  "__v": 0,
  "read": false,
  "links": {
    "self": "/api/books/55afa124168fa1652ce4df21"
  }
}, {
  "_id": "55afa124168fa1652ce4df22",
  "title": "My New Book2",
  "genre": "Fiction2",
  "author": "Jon Mills2",
  "__v": 1,
  "read": false,
  "links": {
    "self": "/api/books/55afa124168fa1652ce4df22"
  }
}];

});
```